# Fetch Album cover art of a song in Android 11 after MediaStore.Audio.Media,DATA is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a music player app and wanted to display the song in recycler view with album art, title, and artist name. To get the album art I tried to use MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA to get the path using which the image can be loaded with the help of Glide. But, because this DATA column has been deprecated my app crashes. I tried to go through the docs as well as search on StackOverflow but didn't find anything. Can anyone provide a detailed explanation as I'm relatively new to Android development. Below is the code I used to fetch the songs from my device. Thanks

```
override fun scanTracks(context: Context): ArrayList<SongModel> {
        val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
        val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            do {
                val album = cursor.getString(0)
                val title = cursor.getString(1)
                val duration = cursor.getString(2)
                val path = cursor.getString(3)
                val artist = cursor.getString(4)

                val songModel = SongModel(path, title, artist, album, duration)

                songList.add(songModel)
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            cursor.close()
        }
        songList.sortWith(Comparator { o1: SongModel, o2: SongModel ->
            o1.songTitle!!.compareTo(o2.songTitle!!)
        })
        return songList
    }
```

Comment: `because this DATA column has been deprecated my app crashes.` Catch the exception that lets your app crash so your app will not crash anymore.

Comment: I can do that but that won't help me to retrieve the album art. I want a solution to get the album art